# Loading ID On Load In Mootools

Tags: mootools

I created a mootool lightbox and my lightbox appears when we click on

```
<a id="HitIt">Click Here</a>
```

I want my lightbox to open as the page loads....please help me ...thanks!

Comment: Please include the link to the lightbox mootools plugin you are using. The answer is most likely already in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What ever you are doing in JavaScript when you click the link move that into a domReady function.

```
window.addEvent ('domready', function(){
     // add code
});
```